# Jar executable wouldn't open new Scene in javaFx

Tags: java, javafx, jar, executable-jar, scenebuilder

When I run my code in Eclipse every window opens with no problems.
First Window leads to the second, and the second leads to the third.

When I made my jar executable and started the application again, the transition from the first to the second windows went the same way as in the eclipse, however, when I clicked Start on a second window, the third window never showed up.
This is what Start Button is responsible for:

```
((Stage)Start.getScene().getWindow()).close();
        Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Board");
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("Media/logo.png"));
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(GameModeController.class.getResource("Board.fxml"));
        BorderPane mainLayout = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainLayout);    
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        controller.RedSpyMasterTerm();
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e->System.exit(0));

        primaryStage.show();
```

First Window: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0rf4.png

Second Window: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLOZm.png

Third Window: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxBPg.png

Location of the files: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeEn3.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPU9p.png

Comment: where us your Board.fxml located? Is it in your classpath?

Comment: I just added a new image Location of the files: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeEn3.png

Comment: Run the `Jar` from the `Command Prompt`. It might show the error there.

Comment: For some reason https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPU9p.png my jar can't find that file. It opens in eclipse, but when I try to find it in jar, it doesn't see it...

Comment: try using `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Board.fxml")` , it may help

Comment: Thank you so much, it really helped !!